# Problem in Localhost using redux-toolkit and redux-persist

Tags: next.js, redux, redux-persist

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import {
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import auth from "./reducers/auth";
import task from "./reducers/task";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 1,
    storage,
    timeout: null,
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
    auth,
    task,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        },
    }).concat([logger]),
});

export default store;
```

layout.js

```
'use client';
import "./globals.css";
import theme from '@/config/muiTheme';
import axios from "axios";
import store from "@/store/store";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:5000";

    let persistor = persistStore(store);

    return (
        <>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <title>To-Do</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <ToastContainer
                        position="bottom-center"
                        autoClose={4000}
                        hideProgressBar={false}
                        newestOnTop={false}
                        closeOnClick
                        rtl={false}
                        pauseOnFocusLoss
                        draggable
                        pauseOnHover
                        theme="dark"
                    />
                    <Provider store={store}>
                    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
                        </PersistGate>
                    </Provider>
                </body>
            </html>
        </>
    );
}
```

authReducer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: {
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        accessToken: null,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        requestStart(state, action) {
            state.loading = true;
        },
        loadUser(state, action) {
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.accessToken = action.payload.accessToken;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.loading = false;
        },
        logOut(state, action) {
            state.user = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.accessToken = null;
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = null;
        },
        resetAuth(state, action) {
            state.user = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.accessToken = null;
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = null;
        },
        requestFail(state, action) {
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export default authSlice.reducer;
export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
```

auth action

```
'use client';
import store from "../store";
import axios from "axios";
import { authActions } from "../reducers/auth";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const { dispatch } = store;

export const createAccount = async (name, email, password) => {
    dispatch(authActions.requestStart());
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(
            '/api/user/',
            { name, email, password }
        );

        const user = res.data.user;
        const accessToken = res.data.token;

        if (res.status === 201) {
            toast.success("User has been saved to the database");
            Cookies.set("Authorization", accessToken, { expires: 5 });
            dispatch(authActions.loadUser({ user, accessToken }));
        } else {
            toast.error("There is some Problem Try Again");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        dispatch(authActions.requestFail(err.message));
        dispatch(authActions.resetAuth());
        toast.error('Signup Failed');
    }
};

export const login = async (email, password) => {
    dispatch(authActions.requestStart());

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(
            '/api/user/login',
            { email, password }
        );

        const { user, accessToken } = res.data;

        if (res.status === 200) {
            toast.success('User has been Logged In');
            Cookies.set("Authorization", accessToken, { expires: 5 });
            dispatch(authActions.loadUser({ user, accessToken }));
        } else {
            toast.error("There is some Problem Try Again");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        dispatch(authActions.requestFail(err.message));
        dispatch(authActions.resetAuth());
        toast.error('Signup Failed');
    }
}
```

Error

```
redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to memory storage.
[1]  action persist/PERSIST @ 10:55:28.811
[1]    prev state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null }
[1]   }
[1]    action     {
[1]     type: 'persist/PERSIST',
[1]     register: [Function: register],
[1]     rehydrate: [Function: rehydrate]
[1]   }
[1]    next state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null },
[1]     _persist: { version: 1, rehydrated: false }
[1]   }
[1]  action persist/REHYDRATE @ 10:55:28.822
[1]    prev state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null },
[1]     _persist: { version: 1, rehydrated: false }
[1]   }
[1]    action     {
[1]     type: 'persist/REHYDRATE',
[1]     payload: undefined,
[1]     err: undefined,
[1]     key: 'root'
[1]   }
[1]    next state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null },
[1]     _persist: { version: 1, rehydrated: true }
[1]   }
[1]  ○ Compiling /not-found ...
[1]  ✓ Compiled /not-found in 751ms (1140 modules)
[1] redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to memory storage.
[1]  action persist/PERSIST @ 10:55:29.995
[1]    prev state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null }
[1]   }
[1]    action     {
[1]     type: 'persist/PERSIST',
[1]     register: [Function: register],
[1]     rehydrate: [Function: rehydrate]
[1]   }
[1]    next state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null },
[1]     _persist: { version: 1, rehydrated: false }
[1]   }
[1]  action persist/REHYDRATE @ 10:55:30.003
[1]    prev state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null },
[1]     _persist: { version: 1, rehydrated: false }
[1]   }
[1]    action     {
[1]     type: 'persist/REHYDRATE',
[1]     payload: undefined,
[1]     err: undefined,
[1]     key: 'root'
[1]   }
[1]    next state {
[1]     auth: {
[1]       user: null,
[1]       isAuthenticated: false,
[1]       accessToken: null,
[1]       loading: true,
[1]       error: null
[1]     },
[1]     task: { task: null, loading: true, error: null },
[1]     _persist: { version: 1, rehydrated: true }
[1]   }
```

[image: This is what i am seeing on my screen]

[image: This is my console]

[image: This is my redux-devtools]

this error occurred when I was setting up redux-persist and then i just cleared my local storage and now i am not able to solve it Please help me to solve this issue and i will also provide more code if you want

I also want to ask one more thing that is redux-persist the only option to persist the state in redux-toolkit other than localstorage

I have tried many solution from stackoverflow and non of them worked

Comment: @DrewReese they are using Next.js client components here, so they have to create the store and everything attached to it (including a persistor) as part of the component tree, otherwise it would be shared between multiple users during SSR of the client components.

Comment: @OP, per my last comment: please start from the [official Next.js guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/nextjs), but be aware that Redux Persist might not have a good place here - your page will prerender on the server in Next.js, even Client Components. And those will never be able to read your browser's localstorage, so they will always render wrong contents.

Comment: @phry Doesn't Next.js suggest devs to create a "makeStore" function that instantiates a store for them? I don't believe this is called as an unintentional side-effect during a component "render" though, right?

Comment: @DrewReese they still have to call that `makeStore` function in a component - but also save that result e.g. in a `ref`, so it's not recomputed on each render. (See the guide :) )

Comment: @phry Well if they are properly using a React ref or state, etc, then it's not an unintentional side-effect.  I just meant don't simply do something like `const store = makeStore();` in the component body.

Comment: @DrewReese True ^^